# How do 2 phones share ITunes and Calendar entries?

Tags: iphone

My husband and I just got iPhones 4 running iOS 6, what we're looking for is to share ITunes and Calendar entries.  We have one computer and right now have Outlook for a calendar.  I want to be able to make one entry on the calendar and have it show up on both phones.  Can I use Outlook to accomplish this?  Or is there an app out there that will sync the computer calendar with both our phones?

Answer (score 1):

My fiancé and I do this quite regularly simply using the iCal app that is part of the phone. We logged in under the same Apple ID and shared only the calendar & contacts (on her phone b/c she doesn't need/want my email). Doing this, we're able to sync calendar and contacts, which is really useful if one of our batteries die.

But you want to use Outlook, it is possible with Outlook, but I think it requires an Exchange service to sync. I'm not 100% sure on that, but I am pretty sure that's what it takes (without manually syncing).

I believe [this post](http://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-5-icloud-tips-sharing-an-apple-id-with-your-family/) will be very useful for you :)